# Android tabs, how to show image for selected tab

Tags: java, android, tabs

the current code shows colors the selected tab.  I would like to change it to now show an image instead.  the commented out code is what I thought would work and not sure why it does not.  what should it be ????

Many thanks.

```
    public void onTabChanged(String tabId) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        for(int i=0;i<mTabHost.getTabWidget().getChildCount();i++)
  {
  TabHost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(i).setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#404040"));


//what I thought would work is this below ?????
//mTabHost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(i).getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.tabimg);


  } 

        mTabHost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(mTabHost.getCurrentTab()).setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#271B1B"));

    }
```

what have I missed.  Thx Again.

Answer (score 0):

Got it.  Found my mistake ....silly of me.   I should have used setBackgroundResource.

```
mTabHost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(i).setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.tabimg);
```

works now.  thx.

Hope this helps someone.